# Is my microwave oven safe to operate?

Tags: microwave

In the middle of the oven, situated opposite the microwave source and below the carousel plate a two inch hole has developed over time. It is found rusted. Presently, when it runs I leave the kitchen after switching it on as a safety  measure. Is it safe to operate it? Can it be repaired? If so, how?

EDIT: The rusted floor (of SAMAR Panasonic) is shown, glass carousel plate removed exposing the hole beneath. Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: Hole in microwave oven floor]

Comment: Why do you leave the kitchen?

Comment: (Excessive) precaution to avoid any microwaves if reflecting through the hole !

Comment: This should really be flagged.  This is super dangerous, please check out the un-edited version of this question.  To the OP.  Throw this item away or take it to a competent, qualified engineer, who I dare say will say. THROW IT AWAY.  Do not switch it on.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 I believe "flagging" is used when an inappropriate question needs moderator attention for serious problems.  This seems like a legitimate question about kitchen equipment.  You answered it pretty clearly.

Comment: With the proliferation of lawsuits I would have thought that staying away from answering a question like this should tell anyone to run away.  This is a dangerous situation in anyone's book, thus should be flagged for this reason.

Comment: This looks totally shot. LITERALLY.

Comment: The oven has since been junked.

Comment: Noooo! You could have placed it on a higher shelf and cook inside it AND under it. You just needed to place your food carefully! Get it back!!! :-)

Comment: Thank you.Shall pass on your suggestion to the possible recipient.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Depends upon the construction of the microwave.  I spoke to an electrical/electronics engineer with over 40 years experience and he said. NO NO NO. Replace it straight away. It could be safe, however without it being in front of him he does not know.